# C++ check if element exists in array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop

I've found a lot of topics like this, but it was kinda too complicated for me.

How to check if element exists in an array?

first I declare an array and put values in it

```
for(int l=0;l<=21;l++){
        skirt[l]=l;
    }
```

and then with another `for` I'd like to check if any element which exist in other array is in array `skirt[];`

Is there a way to write it something like this?

```
for(int k=0;k<=n;k++){
    if(skaiciai[k]!=skirt[k]){
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop:

```
for(int k=0;k<=n;k++){
    if(skaiciai[k]!=skirt[k]){
        counter++;
    }
}
```

would only compare elements at the same index in the arrays. Nested `for` loops are required with the outer `for` loop iterating over the elements in one array and the inner `for` loop iterating over elements in the other array:

```
for (int k_skirt = 0; k_skirt <= n; k_skirt++)
{
    for (int k_skaiciai = 0; k_skaiciai <= n; k_skaiciai++)
    {
        if(skaiciai[k_skaicia] == skirt[k_skirt]){
            counter++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this would be to use standard algorithm, rather than a handwritten loop:

```
if (std::find_first_of(
        skirt, skirt + skirt_size,
        skaiciai, skaiciai + skaiciai_size)
    != skirt + skirt_size)
{
    //skirt contained an element from skaiciai
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could simply use the std::count algorithm.

```
auto counter = std::count( skirt, skirt+skirt_size );
```

Comment: This would not compile, as you omitted any value or predicate to compare against; no overload of `std::count()` takes only 2 arguments, as it needs the 3rd to tell it _what_ to count. And it's how to count using nesting that is the question.