# How can I check if given int exists in array?

Tags: c++, arrays

For example, I have this array:

```
int myArray[] = { 3, 6, 8, 33 };
```

How to check if given variable x is in it?

Do I have to write my own function and loop the array, or is there in modern c++ equivalent to `in_array` in PHP?

Comment: Look at the example for [`std::find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/).

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can use [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) for this:

```
#include <algorithm> // for std::find
#include <iterator> // for std::begin, std::end

int main () 
{
  int a[] = {3, 6, 8, 33};
  int x = 8;
  bool exists = std::find(std::begin(a), std::end(a), x) != std::end(a);
}
```

`std::find` returns an iterator to the first occurrence of `x`, or an iterator to one-past the end of the range if `x` is not found.

Comment: Or simply:  `bool exists = std::any_of(std::begin(array), std::end(array), [&](int i) { return i == x; });`

Comment: `std::find` is nice if you aren't on C++ 11. Then again `std:begin` and `std:end` are C++ 11 only.

Comment: How can I do it on a non-hardcoded array?  Error no matching function for call to 'std::begin'` Like this  `int *squaresPlayerMarked = new int[5]();
  int x = 8;
  bool exists = std::find(std::begin(squaresPlayerMarked), std::end(a), squaresPlayerMarked) != std::end(a);
  std::cout << exists;`

Comment: @MoteZart All you have is a pointer, so you need to keep track of the array length, and then use it to get the past-the-end iterator, for example `squaresPlayerMarked + 5`.

Answer (score 17):

I think you are looking for [`std::any_of`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of), which will return a true/false answer to detect if an element is in a container (array, vector, deque, etc.)

```
int val = SOME_VALUE; // this is the value you are searching for
bool exists = std::any_of(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray), [&](int i)
{
    return i == val;
});
```

If you want to know where the element is, [`std::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find) will return an iterator to the first element matching whatever criteria you provide (or a predicate you give it).

```
int val = SOME_VALUE;
int* pVal = std::find(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray), val);
if (pVal == std::end(myArray))
{
    // not found
}
else
{
    // found
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>


int main () {
  int myArray[] = { 3 ,6 ,8, 33 };
  int x = 8;

  if (std::any_of(std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray), [=](int n){return n == x;}))   {
      std::cout << "found match/" << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You almost never have to write your own loops in C++.  Here, you can use [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find).

```
const int toFind = 42;
int* found = std::find (myArray, std::end (myArray), toFind);
if (found != std::end (myArray))
{
  std::cout << "Found.\n"
}
else
{
  std::cout << "Not found.\n";
}
```

`std::end` requires C++11.  Without it, you can find the number of elements in the array with:

```
const size_t numElements = sizeof (myArray) / sizeof (myArray[0]);
```

...and the end with:

```
int* end = myArray + numElements;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int index = std::distance(std::begin(myArray), std::find(begin(myArray), end(std::myArray), VALUE));
```

Returns an invalid index (length of the array) if not found.

Answer (score -4):

You do need to loop through it. C++ does not implement any simpler way to do this when you are dealing with primitive type arrays.

also see this answer: [C++ check if element exists in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079712/c-check-if-element-exists-in-array)

Comment: Yes it does -- std::find.  It's still a loop in the end, but a loop that's already been written.

Comment: The linked question even has an answer involving std::find_first_of...

Comment: `std::find`, `std::find_first_of`, `std::any_of`.  They all implement loops, but the language has provided them for you (so you do not need to write your own).  In C++, most of the time you will rarely have to write your own loop.

Comment: The language provides overloads of `std::(c)(r)(begin|end)` for raw arrays so that they can be processed by algorithms using unified syntax. Even before those debuted, pointers into (or, of course, one-past-the-end of) raw arrays could be used as iterators. Like, iterators are a _superset_ of pointers, so of course.