# How can I write a template to check if a given value is in an array

Tags: c++, arrays

Per an answer to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299508/how-can-i-check-if-given-int-exists-in-array), I wrote the template below which should return true if the array contains the passed value, and false otherwise.

```
template <typename Type>
bool Contains(const Type container[], const Type& value) {
  return std::any_of(
      std::begin(container), std::end(container),
      [&value](const Type& contained_value) { return value == contained_value; });
}
```

When I try to compile, I get the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'begin'
      std::begin(container), std::end(container),
```

What is causing `std::begin` to fail? The [std::begin documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) shows it works with arrays. In this specific instance, I am instantiating the template on an enum (not an enum class).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type for `Contains` is wrong so that `container` was deduced to be `const int *&`, which have no override for `std:begin`

Error message from g++ is more clear:

> main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘bool Contains(const Type*, const Type&)
>   [with Type = int]’: main.cpp:18:34:   required from here
>
> main.cpp:9:17: error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(const
>   int*&)’

This is fixed code. You need to pass the array as array type (`int[3]`) in order for `std::end` to figure out the length of array from the type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename Type, std::size_t N>
bool Contains(Type (&container)[N], const Type& value) {
  return std::any_of(
      std::begin(container), std::end(container),
      [&value](const Type& contained_value) { return value == contained_value; });
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = {1,2,3};
    int val = 1;
    int val2 = 4;
    bool result = Contains(a, val);
    bool result2 = Contains(a, val2);
    std::cout << result << std::endl;
    std::cout << result2 << std::endl;
}
```