# C++ Find an int in an array

Tags: c++

So I've read other Stack posts about this, and they all suggest that I use `find`. I'm attempting this, but it doesn't work for me.

```
bool findInArray(int number, int array[]){
    // Finds if the number is in the array
    bool exists = find(begin(array), end(array), number) != end(array);
    return exists;
```

}

But I keep getting the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘begin(int*&)’
```

It's even the accepted answer here: [How can I check if given int exists in array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299508/how-can-i-check-if-given-int-exists-in-array)

Comment: why do you pass an array pointer instead of an array as a parameter to 'findInArray'?

Comment: Because in your function you don't have an array, you have a *pointer*.

Comment: I don't know why I left that there. I'd been trying all sorts of things and I missed that. I've edited to what it actually looks like.

Comment: In your example, `int array[]` has an unknown size, there is no way for `std::end` to know where the end of the array is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a template:

```
template <std::size_t N>
bool findInArray(int number, const int (&array)[N]) {
  // Finds if the number is in the array
  return std::find(std::begin(array), std::end(array), number) != std::end(array);
}
```

You also need to pass the array by lvalue, since you cannot pass arrays by prvalue in C++, and instead the array would decay to a pointer to its first element, thereby losing the size information.

Comment: Thanks. This appears to be the answer, but I'm not familiar with templates yet. I'll read up on those.

Answer (score 1):

In case you do not know template and looking for an other answer to this question, use STL algorithms.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>

bool findInArray(int number, int array[], int size_array){
  int* p   = std::find(array, array+size_array, number);
  if (p != array+size_array) {
    return 1;
  } else {
   return 0;
}
```

And from main, you can call :

```
findInArray(5, a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]));
```